# how to remove fullscreen button in jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, jwplayer

I need to remove the `fullscreen` button in jwplayer. What do I need to do?

**Code**

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/jwplayer/player.swf" width="100%" height="300" id="Player" name="Player">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="wmode" value="transaparent">
<param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+id+'&autostart=true&playlist=over&dock=true&repeat=list">
</object>
```

Comment: Try setting `<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">` to `false`?

Comment: yes i trying this yesterday but not working :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution. Download the sources of Jwplayer from the GitHub repo (of course use the same version as what you're using):

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/releases

In `assets/` there must be a file named `six.xml` (the default skin). remove the following lines:

```
<element name="fullscreenButton" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAcCAYAAAB75n/uAAAAbElEQVR42u2R0QnAIAxEu1lWc5/+ZYKs4TTWjwS0qIFrP+/BkYMLOdCLELKn1tpG5TleYF2yyMUzvCAOZDtwgU85PJGE/+NPyuTJG1Uts/9+sI0+y6GCrtunLHKJHbjAZYcd8x28IJTmhJAtD4gEt9ueDIktAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
<element name="fullscreenButtonOver" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAcCAYAAAB75n/uAAACFUlEQVR42t2W324SURCHhS67VCoFbYhRkbQsaCwVSwgUaZP2yia9Mb6MN41vYfpIfYIm5QIegJfA3yTfSU52c1i98KabfGGYmd+cPX+Gw7On+2w2m5JPUfxfC5dhB8pQKooXvjGCiohFFRJ8EVTwVSHGtxOckSuOsCb2xUsDe0/swl42jiZxg2wr/kK0REf0DOzX4hXIzsVbaPODsH4VUSOxL8biwsD+SCEhOx/vo61Rq5zd1JipdhBkn6k4hmk2iKZDjdhtuj9Awnqm4twTPopf4lKM4BLfo0tCk1IjCQ3QFF0xR+QK/BBXYgxX+PycOdpmaAC3RG1xiui7uMWeic8ww3dLzgZNO7tEoU1OxYhpX7Dmd+KDgT0ldk5umt/k/DGtioZ4y/E7EUMx4JQcQR/fkJwemgY1OKbhAd6wnscU+ESRQ+jhOyGniyY4QFlE4rk4sCKIJyzFaLVa/XaNhT0iNiH30LTUiEJ9UGeqg8ViYRv3TVxjj80PY3zXloM9QFvf1gcN3mRiIr3pvX2u1+ufHMMvMDefn2MatI2iPjgSZyYylsvlg77fiK/umGLfWMzlmQbt3/UBQoc7530IxLf3QeT3AYIZbzbE9w5SfGfknGb6IAr1Qez9XL8XXabdxtc0sNvEuuS20MZFd0LsXThNqOOrQg0fcS6cXPHiKzOB2L8yg3GKG4WXfoBSUfz//W15ss8fvEcYMYnLr+AAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
```

And then, when you call JwPlayer, insert in the skin option the path of your modified skin:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  file: "/upload/myVideo.mp4",
  skin: "your-modified-six.xml"
});
```

Beware that double clicking on the player still enables fullscreen. You should disable it on the code too (not just the frontend), by editing the source code of jwplayer.js. Search for `allowfullscreen`, and set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following skin:

[Simple Skin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/skins/51/Simple)

Comment: i know this skin, but its very simple i need only full screen remove becouse i wana play only audio from youtume

Comment: Just take a look at the standard template then. I think it wont be too difficault to find the button and remove it :)

Comment: i found at skin.xml the element buttons, and i remove the fullscreen button, but nothing has changed :(